# How to install C++ compiler for Eclipse

Tags: fedora, eclipse, compiler

Im unable to run my C++ codes because Eclipse has not c++ compiler installed in it . How can I install C++ compiler for eclipse on Fedora 20 or other linux os's?

When I execute my codes it says:

```
Launch fails. Binary not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I install C++ compiler for eclipse on Fedora 20?

```
yum install gcc-c++
```